# Flash Builder - Scroll with crtl+left/right messed up

Tags: flash-builder4.5

I must have triggered some setting, but in Flash Builder 4.5 now, when I try to skip past a word using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, it will stop at the nearest capital letter instead of jumping the whole word.
Does anyone know how to return this to the normal functionality?

ex:

```
m_stopDoingThisFlashBuilder
```

While holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, it will take 5 keystrokes on left/right arrow to navigate past, instead of the usual 1.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue where it stops at every capital letter, you can **disable**:

**"Use sub-word caret positioning in code"**

under

***[Preferences]*** > Flash Builder > Editors

Unfortunately, It will still stop before and after underscores... Which is VERY annoying, since I use m_memberVariables as well

If anyone figures out how to fix that, please post! :-)